# Cannot use username on bitbucket any more - how to update on sourceTree?

Tags: bitbucket.org

I used to be able to use my username (not email) on bitbucket to access:

```
https://thisisme@bitbucket.org/thisisme/somerepo.git
```

Now I can no longer use my username, but must login via my email and password.  And `pull` no longer works for me.  How do I update my "username" locally to be my email?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Though your login creds may have changed on BitBucket (they had migrated to a common system for Atlassian a while ago), your git commandline use **can continue to use** your userid.

The password however, must be your Atlassian account password. At least, that's how I'm using it. I know... "it works for me" is cliched, but it could help - especially if you were trying (and failing) to use the old BitBucket password.

To be sure, copy-paste the https url from your bitbucket repo online.
Of course, you could use the other one - the ssh / git: URL.